# Condition without using another feature file call

Tags: automated-tests, karate

Using Karate, I would like to know, if it is possible to set If condition without necessity of calling different feature file (and not using JavaScript) -> using block of Karate feature file code in condition:

e.g. it should be possible to do something like that?

```
* if (variable==1) {
     * delay(3000)
     * retry().click('{button[3]/span}Text1')
     } 
     {
     * retry().click('{button[2]/span}Text2')
     * delay(3000)
      }
```

Is it possible to do somehow like this without using separate feature file with only few rows of code? Do you have any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, use the `eval` keyword - and you can do "pure" JS and on multiple lines:

```
* eval
"""
  if (variable == 1) {
    delay(3000);
    retry().click('{button[3]/span}Text1');
  } else {
   retry().click('{button[2]/span}Text2');
   delay(3000);
  }
"""
```

By the way, since you seem to be doing a lot of advanced testing, I suggest you start using the 1.0 RC version so that you don't get any surprises and you can provide feedback also: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/1.0-upgrade-guide

Comment: Thank you! It works fine. Btw: I will check 1.0 upgrade guide. Thanks.